# Why haven't I got additional reputation since the question votes recalc?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Recently it was announced that question upvotes are now going to be worth +10 reputation rather than +5. When is this change going to have fully taken effect on this sub-site? Because I've seen loads of people say that they have received their additional rep, but I haven't changed yet, and I have a good few highly upvoted questions...

To clarify, I have read the other post, but the answer there says the recalc has finished, but it doesn't appear to have finished for me yet.

Comment: FWIW are you asking because you've seen no big green + number in the top bar or because you don't think there was any change? If the former, you wouldn't, no one did. The change was retroactive so technically you've always had that rep.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot If that is the case than the change must have happened quite early on for me, because the day the blog post was released I checked my rep on SciFi and it was the same as it is now.

Comment: [This very rough SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1148164/estimated-rep-bump-from-question-upvote-change) estimates a maximum gain for you of 875 rep. However, you have to consider the rep cap of 200 daily so you'd be falling somewhere between 0 and 875 on the increase.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Oh, ok thanks. I had forgotten about the rep cap.

Comment: Perhaps you got bit by a retroactive spider, thus negating any bonus you might have received, instead gaining some super powers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your reputation has already been recalculated.

As a moderator I can see a log in your user history which notes a reputation recalculation at November 13 19:34:47Z from 2,074 to 2,738.

You can also confirm for yourself that you have received 10 reputation per question upvote by looking at your reputation history, either [in your profile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/84035/james-douglas?tab=reputation&sort=post) or by browsing to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/reputation while logged in.

Note that the recalculation took into account the daily reputation cap so you did not necessarily receive twice as much reputation from your question upvotes. Also, the green reputation indicator in the top bar did not notify anyone of a reputation increase due to the recalculation -- your reputation score simply updated when the recalculation was complete.

Comment: For a few hours during the process, the value shown on a given site and the value shown in the site selector on the right did not match.